# What is JRuby-Rack?

Tags: ruby, jruby, rack, jruby-rack

I have an existing web application written in Ruby using rack and thin. I need to port this to JRuby so that it can interface with some Java libraries. Google pointed me to this page: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JRuby_Rack

What is this JRuby-Rack? I don't know enough about Ruby to seem to figure it out and there does not seem to be any tutorials. I do not know what is warble and the only example I have seen involves rails which I am not using.

If there is a less painful way of doing this please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want its [official release announcement](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2008/05/08/introducing-jruby-rack), or [its homepage](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby-rack/pages/Home):

From the home page

> JRuby-Rack is a lightweight adapter for the Java servlet environment that allows any Rack-based application to run unmodified in a Java servlet container. JRuby-Rack supports Rails, Merb, and any Rack-compatible Ruby web framework.